# How safe are my cookies, when using proxy only in one of my browsers?

Tags: proxy, cookies

I would need to use proxy for simulating visit my websites from other countries. I am aware, that using proxy means, that my cookies in the browser are not safe. As I understand, it is regarding only that particular browser, that has proxy set? As I understand, the cookies from other browsers should be still safe?

EDIT: For example, if I have cookies with my bank credentials in Chrome, and I use Proxy only in Mozilla, it means, that cookies in Chrome are safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @TOM, other browsers remain intact of course. If the proxy is set for particular browser, then it affects only that browser (of course if you havent installed PROXY software, that changes whole system).

As @Ouroborus mentioned, you'd better clear all cookies in that browser, or open PRIVATE window and access proxy there.

Answer (score 1):

Any cookies that are passed through the proxy can be considered exposed. This is basically any cookie associated with any request (page, image, etc.) or submission (forms, etc.) your browser processes.

There are some tricks to get browsers to pass along unrelated cookies. MDN's page on [HTTP Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) gives an example originally from Wikipedia:

> **Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)**
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cross-site_request_forgery) mentions a good example for CSRF. In this situation, someone includes an image that isn’t really an image (for example in an unfiltered chat or forum), instead it really is a request to your bank’s server to withdraw money:
>
> ```
> <img src="http://bank.example.com/withdraw?account=bob&amount=1000000&for=mallory">
> ```
>
> Now, if you are logged into your bank account and your cookies are still valid (and there is no other validation), you will transfer money as soon as you load the HTML that contains this image.

By guessing common sites, it would be possible for a page to use this technique to get the browser to send, along with the request, a cookie containing an active session key even if the requested content were invalid. The proxy could then pick up the cookie and make use of it.

HTTPS can help mitigate all of this, but it depends on how the particular proxy works. Proxies can perform [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks on the connection by replacing the SSL certificate with another, trusted certificate.

Modern browsers offer the ability to open a "privacy" window or tab that behave as though there are no previous cookies in existence (among other things). None of your pre-existing cookies are shared with the private window.

Comment: thanks for answer. My question was mostly regarding using multiple browsers. If I have cookies with my bank credentials in Chrome, and I use Proxy only in Mozilla, it means, that cookies in Chrome are safe?

Comment: @tomas.teicher That's correct.